# what is the use case and difference between db.getreplicationinfo() vs rs.printreplicationinfo() in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

1- what is the use case and difference between db.getreplicationinfo()
    vs rs.printreplicationinfo() in mongodb. when i run the both
    commands in repliaset as resulted below. Can anyone explain me the
    difference between the two commands and use cases.

```
(mongod-3.4.9)[PRIMARY:s0] local> db.getReplicationInfo()`
`

{
  "logSizeMB": 6714.337890625,
  "usedMB": 208.66,
  "timeDiff": 2152896,
  "timeDiffHours": 598.03,
  "tFirst": "Sat Sep 23 2017 17:48:27 GMT+0530 (IST)",
  "tLast": "Wed Oct 18 2017 15:50:03 GMT+0530 (IST)",
  "now": "Wed Oct 18 2017 15:50:09 GMT+0530 (IST)"
}


(mongod-3.4.9)[PRIMARY:s0] local> db.getReplicationInfo()

{
  "logSizeMB": 6714.337890625,
  "usedMB": 208.66,
  "timeDiff": 2152896,
  "timeDiffHours": 598.03,
  "tFirst": "Sat Sep 23 2017 17:48:27 GMT+0530 (IST)",
  "tLast": "Wed Oct 18 2017:50:03 GMT+0530 (IST)",
  "now": "Wed Oct 18 2017 15:50:09 GMT+0530 (IST)"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation:
[db.printReplicationInfo()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.printReplicationInfo/) formats and prints the data returned by db.getReplicationInfo():

db.getReplicationInfo() sends back an object/document that you can use in a script.